# Repeating a spring batch task to read multiple files

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I need to process multiple files with spring batch. I used MultiResourceItemReader and it works, but then I got the following requirements :

1. Before processing a file do some check and possibly skip processing the file
2. Log when file an input file reading is started, writing is in progress and finished writing

The 1st requirement can be easily met, but the 2nd is problematic for multiple reasons :
 1. The writer has no reference to the input resource, it only receives a list of POJOs
 2. A chunk might contain POJOS that were read from multiple input files.

I was thinking in a few solutions solutions

1. Implement a flow with a loop in it using a JobExecutionDecider. In this case the step would only process a single file, and the loop would iterate over all resources
2. Repeat the step somehow and the step would keep track the list of files
3. include the resource in the POJO.

I am using java based config and the documentation is quite vague on case 1. and 2. as it only explains using XML. What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: To bw aware of resource in use check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993633/get-current-resource-name-using-multiresourceitemreader-spting-batch/23005065#23005065); with a custom ItemReader I think you can solve the problem pretty easy

Comment: Actually the second is pretty easy. The `MultiResourceItemReader` delegates the actual reading to a `ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream` (which is an interface). When it starts to read a file the `open` method is called, when it ends the `close` method is called (even when it switches from one resource to another). Everything in between is basically in progress. You can quite easily implement a delegating implementation of the `ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream` which does some logging in the `open` and `close` methods. Is there something specific you need it for?

Comment: The problem is that the writers. If I read three 1 line input file and chunk size is set to 4 then the writer will receive a list with three POJO, each coming from a different input file. In this case how do I log that an input file is fully written to the output? One option would be to make the Pojos implement the ResourceAware interface, so each POJO would hold a reference to the file it was read from. The problem is that adds spring batch dependency to the POJOs. I am still wondering if there would be any cleaner solution