# Spring Batch job: get the file name in the itemprocessor

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, jobs

I am reading the files from the multiresource reader.I am processing the data in the itemprocessor .In the itemprocessor i want to get the filename for which the record is not correct.

My job configuration:-

```
<batch:job id="FtpJob">
            <batch:step id="step2">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceItemReader" processor="itemProcessor"
                    writer="databaseItemWriter" commit-interval="100">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="multiResourceItemReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
        <property name="resources"
            value="file:C:/Users/Sandeep/Documents/New/*" />
        <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemReader" />
    </bean>

    <!-- ItemReader reads a complete line one by one from input file -->
    <bean id="flatFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughLineMapper">
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="itemProcessor" class="Processor.itemProcessor"
        scope="step">
    </bean>

    <!-- ItemWriter which writes data to database -->
    <bean id="databaseItemWriter"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemWriter">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

My Item Processor Class:-

```
public class itemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Object,Data> {
public Cdr process(Object singleLine) throws Exception
{
// here i want to know the record singleLine  i am processing is of which file
// processing the code here
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993633/get-current-resource-name-using-multiresourceitemreader-spting-batch

Comment: Took some time to figure out that the ResourceAware needs to be implemented on the 'Item'  class and not the 'Processor' class. Which makes sense, each item would know which resource it had been read from ...