# Resource name not reflecting on second file correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application where my `Model` is `ResourceAware`.

I am reading multiple files in my application:

```
@Data
@Slf4j
public class Model implements ResourceAware {


private String countryCode;
private Resource resource;

public Resource getResource() {
    return resource;
}

@Override
public void setResource(Resource resource) {
    this.resource = resource;
}
```

}

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private MyReader reader;


@Bean
@StepScope
public MultiResourceItemReader<Model> multiResourceItemReader() {

    PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();

    MultiResourceItemReader<Model> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();

    final File resourceLocation = FileManager.getResourcesLocationAsFile(filePath);

    String url = "file:" + resourceLocation.getAbsolutePath();

    if (resourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
        url = url + SEPERATOR + filePattern + "*";
    }

    Resource[] resources = new Resource[0];


    try {
        resources = resolver.getResources(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    resourceItemReader.setStrict(true);
    resourceItemReader.setResources(resources);
    resourceItemReader.setDelegate(reader());

    return resourceItemReader;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<Model> reader() {
    return reader.getReader();
}


@Bean
public ItemProcessor<Model, SCPModel> modelProcessor() {
    return new ModelProcessor();
}
```

}

When I write to the database, the file name is always the first file that was processed even though the second file record were inserted into the database?

What trick am I missing here? In my `processor` I am setting the filename as follows:

```
@Override
    public SCPModel process(final Model model) throws Exception {

        scp.setResource(model.getResource().getFilename());
        return scp;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of your job config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I did not have the right static setup in the database for one of my resource files. I printed to console the items of a reader and the resource was correctly reflected.