# Accessing name of flat file from FlatFileItemReader LineMapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a need to be able to access the name of the flat file that the current line being read is from. We are porting an application and some processes that are currently in place require this information.

Here is my current configuration:

```
private FlatFileItemReader<Invoice> invoiceFlatFileItemReader() throws Exception {
    FlatFileItemReader<Invoice> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1); // header row
    reader.setLineMapper(new InvoiceLineMapper());
    reader.afterPropertiesSet();

    return reader;
}
```

InvoiceLineMapper:

```
public class InvoiceLineMapper implements LineMapper<Invoice> {

    @Override
    public Invoice mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
        String[] fields = line.split(",");
        ArrayList<String> fieldList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            fieldList.add(fields[i].replaceAll("\"", "");
        }

        Invoice invoice = new Invoice();

        invoice.setCustomerNumber(Integer.parseInt(fieldList.get(0));
        invoice.setCustomerName(fieldList.get(1));

        // set other things and stuff...

        //Need to be able to set the file name on the model here
        invoice.setFileName(theFileName);
    }
}
```

I am delegating to the `invoiceFlatFileItemReader()` via a `MultiResourceItemReader`:

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<Invoice> invoiceItemReader() throws Exception {
    ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatterResolver(this.getClass().getClassLoader());

    // currently being loaded from the classpath, eventually will be read from S3...that comes later
    Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:**/InvoiceList*.csv*"); 

    MultiResourceItemReader<Invoice> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    reader.setResources(resources);
    reader.setDelegate(invoiceFlatFileItemReader());

    return reader;
}
```

**How can I get the name of the resource passed down the chain to where I can access it in the `InvoiceLineMapper` class and add it to the model (which later gets persisted with a `RepositoryItemWriter`)?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current resource name using MultiResourceItemReader Spting batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993633/get-current-resource-name-using-multiresourceitemreader-spting-batch)

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I ended up doing, just passing the `MultiItemResourceReader` down the chain so that I could call `getCurrentResource()` in the line mapper:

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<Invoice> invoiceItemReader() throws Exception {
    ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatterResolver(this.getClass().getClassLoader());

    // currently being loaded from the classpath, eventually will be read from S3...that comes later
    Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:**/InvoiceList*.csv*"); 

    MultiResourceItemReader<Invoice> reader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    reader.setResources(resources);
    reader.setDelegate(invoiceFlatFileItemReader(reader));

    return reader;
}

private FlatFileItemReader<Invoice> invoiceFlatFileItemReader(MultiResourceItemReader delegator) throws Exception {
    FlatFileItemReader<Invoice> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1); // header row
    reader.setLineMapper(new InvoiceLineMapper(delegator));
    reader.afterPropertiesSet();

    return reader;
}
```

And then in `InvoiceLineMapper`:

```
public class InvoiceLineMapper implements LineMapper<Invoice> {

    private MultiResourceItemReader delegator;

    public InvoiceLineMapper(MultiResourceItemReader delegator) {
         this.delegator = delegator;
    }

    @Override
    public Invoice mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
        String[] fields = line.split(",");
        ArrayList<String> fieldList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            fieldList.add(fields[i].replaceAll("\"", "");
        }

        Invoice invoice = new Invoice();

        invoice.setCustomerNumber(Integer.parseInt(fieldList.get(0));
        invoice.setCustomerName(fieldList.get(1));

        // set other things and stuff...

        Resource currentResource = delegator.getCurrentResource();
        String[] fileName = currentResource.getFilename().split("/");

        invoice.setFileName(filename[filename.length - 1]);

        return invoice;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an interface `ResourceAware` that your item can implement.  If it does implement that interface, when using `MultiResourceItemReader`, the resource will be injected automatically for you.  You can read more about the `ResourceAware` interface in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ResourceAware.html

Comment: ResourceAware never did actually work for me @michael-minella ... just wanted to give you an update.

Comment: it's just an *@Entity annotated POJO

Comment: That implements `ResourceAware`?

Comment: Ah, then I misunderstood entirely. I thought LineMapper should also implement ResourceAware, since that's where I was trying to `setFilename`

Comment: I see now you say "item"... I am a giddy goat

Comment: :)  Your item should implement it.  The `MultiResourceItemReader` will handle setting it for you if you do.