# Spring Batch - Get FileName inside a CustomLineMapper when using MultiResourceItemReader

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using a **Item** with the inferface **ResourceAware** implemented to get the current resource filename. I get it in the **ItemProcessor** and this is working fine to log a complete information about the error.

Anyway, I want get the fileName if the moment of the FieldSetMapper throw an Exception, to register the line content, the line number and the file name but I don't found the correct way.

This is my current code:

```
public class MyCustomLineMapper<T> implements LineMapper<BaseDTO>, InitializingBean  {

        private LineTokenizer tokenizer;
        private BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<BaseDTO> fieldSetMapper;

        public BaseDTO mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {

            try {
                BaseDTO r = fieldSetMapper.mapFieldSet(tokenizer.tokenize(line));
                r.setLineNumber(lineNumber);
                r.setLineContent(line);
                return r;
            } catch(Exception ex){
                BaseDTO r = new BaseDTO();
                r.setError(String.format(Keys.LINE_PARSE_ERROR, lineNumber, "FILE_NAME", line));
                return r;
                /// I want use the current filename in this moment.
            }
        }

        public void setLineTokenizer(LineTokenizer tokenizer) {
            this.tokenizer = tokenizer;
        }

        public void setFieldSetMapper(BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<BaseDTO> fieldSetMapper) {
            this.fieldSetMapper = fieldSetMapper;
        }

        public void afterPropertiesSet() {
            Assert.notNull(tokenizer, "The LineTokenizer must be set");
            Assert.notNull(fieldSetMapper, "The FieldSetMapper must be set");
        }

}
```

In my item "**BaseDTO**" I implemented **ResourceAware** like this:

```
public class BaseDTO implements ResourceAware {

    protected String itemClassifier;
    protected String error;
    protected int lineNumber;
    protected String lineContent;
    protected Resource res;
    protected String fileName;

    @Override
    public void setResource(Resource res) {
        this.res = res;
        this.fileName = res.getFilename();
    }
```

But in case of an exception reading a file (IncorrecNumberOfTokens by Example) I need get my item from FieldSetMapper with this field filled but the exception stop this. How can I achieve this?

Sorry for my english. Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: what do you mean by "when using MultiResourceFileName"? Do you mean `MultiResourceItemReader`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I misspelled these. Thanks for notice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing name of flat file from FlatFileItemReader LineMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097612/accessing-name-of-flat-file-from-flatfileitemreader-linemapper)