# How to pass parameters from ItemReader to ItemProcessor in spring-batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Question is simple: how can I pass a value that is only know within `ItemReader` (eg the current filename) to the `ItemProcessor`?

```
@Bean
@JobScope
public ItemReader<String> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['path]}") String path) {
    FlatFileItemReader<String> delegate = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    delegate.setLineMapper(new PassThroughLineMapper());

    Resource[] res = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("file:" + path);

    MultiResourceItemReader<String> r = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    r.setResources(res);
    r.setDelegate(delegate);
    return r;
}

@Bean
public ItemProcessor<String, String> processor() {
    return new ItemProcessor<String, String>() {

        @Override
        public String process(String item) throws Exception {
            //TODO I need the filename that is currently processed. HOW?
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Why can't you pass POJO or Map rather than String?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993633/get-current-resource-name-using-multiresourceitemreader-spting-batch)

Comment: @StanislavL because if I read a file with some million lines, I'd have to create also some million useless pojos.

Comment: @SabirKhan what do you think answers the question there? Your linked question has even NO accepted answer.

Comment: I guess , accepting or not accepting an answer is totally asker's prerogative . I think, `ResourceAware` approach should work for you. Or another simple way to get all resources before beginning your step and injecting values in reader and processor both from step context. Have you tried `ResourceAware` approach? There is a link to a spring forum thread in first answer.

Comment: `ResourceAware` is to be applied on the `Item` that is read from `ItemReader`. As written above, I just have a `FlatFileItemReader<String>`. Not the `<String>`, which means I do NOT have an object that could `implement ResourceAware`. So I would have to introduce an object that has two fields: the content string, and the resource. But I'd like to avoid this, as I would have to create that pojo for each string (=for each line in the file). That's bad for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably best to introduce a dto for the reader.

```
public class ResourceAwareString implements ResourceAware {
     private String content;
     private Resource res;

     @Override
     public void setResource(Resource res) {
         this.res = res;
     }
}
```

Then the `MultiResourceItemReader<ResourceAwareString>` will automatically detect it and write the resource to the dto.

Other approach would be to make both `ItemReader` and `ItemProcessor` `@StepScope` and use `@BeforeStep` to get access to the current `StepExection` context. Then it's possible to set/get a value, and thereby transport values from reader to processer, or even to writer.

Note that `@BeforeStep` only works on a public class, and NOT on an anonymous method like:

```
new FlatFileItemReader<String>() {
  @BeforeStep
  public void before(StepExecution stepEx) {
       //this will never be called! don't do this.
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to be on the safe side, you should add the name of the file to the object that is returned by the reader. In order to do that, you have to implement your own wrapper Reader. Something like this:

```
public class MyReader {
     private MultiResourceItemReader delegatereader;

     public MyContainerDto read() {
          String line = delegatereader.read();
          if (line==null) return null;

          Resource currentResource = delegatereader.getCurrentResource();

          MyContainerDto container = MyContainerDto();
          container.setLine(line);
          container.setResourceName(currentResource.getFileName());
          return container;
     }

     ...
}
```

(this code was not tested, it just illustrates the aproach I would take)

On my laptop, I'm able to crate 1 million objects within a second, so the additional performance needed in order to create the objects isn't really something that affects the overall performance significantly.

The problem is, that the reader reads as many items, as is defined by the chunksize. After that, it will call the processor for every item in this chunk. Therefore, within a chunk, the items in it could have been read from different files. Hence, there is no other way than to bind the line and the filename together in the reader.

see also https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/03/transactions-in-spring-batch-part-1-the-basics/