# How to get resource in itemreader using spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using spring batch for batch processing.

I am using MultiResourceItemReader to initialize the reader object. I did set the resources.

In FlatFileItemReader, i wanted to get the current filename so that i can manipulate data based on filename.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current resource name using MultiResourceItemReader Spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993633/get-current-resource-name-using-multiresourceitemreader-spring-batch)

Comment: Implemented ResourceAware, but i couldn't get the resource.

Comment: spring batch 3.0.7

Comment: Show your code please.

Answer (score 0):

```
MultiResourceItemReader#getCurrentResource()
```

This returns the currentResource being read, and Resource has getFileName method which you can use to get the name.