# How to get the currentresource of MultiResourrceItemReader using java config

Tags: spring-batch

Below is the code I tried.

```
@Bean
public MultiResourceItemReader<Map<String, String>> multiResourceItemReader() throws FileNotFoundException {
    MultiResourceItemReader<Map<String, String>> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<Map<String, String>>();
    inputResources=getMultipleResourceItemreader();
    resourceItemReader.setResources(inputResources);
    resourceItemReader.setDelegate(reader());
    return resourceItemReader;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current resource name using MultiResourceItemReader Spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993633/get-current-resource-name-using-multiresourceitemreader-spring-batch)

Comment: To get the current resource of the `MultiResourceItemReader`, you use the `getCurrentResource` method: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemReader.html#getCurrentResource-- . Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: getCurrentResource() method returning null

Comment: In this case, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993633/get-current-resource-name-using-multiresourceitemreader-spring-batch

Comment: The problem is that i return FlatFileItemReader<Map<String, String>>.Hence not able to implement ResourceAware

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ResourceAware` interface to get the resource name.Your `Iteam` should implement `ResourceAware` interface.

```
 class Foo implements ResourceAware {

        String value;
        Resource resource;

        Foo(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public void setResource(Resource resource) {
            this.resource = resource;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have pojo to implement ResourceAware Interface

Comment: public FlatFileItemReader<Map<String, String>> reader() throws FileNotFoundException,IOException{
 FlatFileItemReader<Map<String, String>> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Map<String, String>>();
 //logic
  return reader;
}

Comment: Can you wrap <Map<String String>>() to any custom object?